# Black Screen when second external HDD is plugged in

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have my Ubuntu running off an external HDD and now I’m trying to plug in another external HDD to use while Ubuntu is already booted which causes it to freak out and black screen with some text about read-only stuff.

One thing I think might be the issue is that I have my laptop set to boot automatically from the usb HDD so it might be trying to boot from the empty HDD when I plugged it in.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do I read this right? You boot Ubuntu and then remove the drive the OS is on and plug in a different drive?

Comment: No sorry that was a bit confusing, I have two separate usb External Hard drives I want plugged in at the same time. The one with the OS is first so it can boot off that one then I want to plug in a second one to use for storage. I can’t get the second one plugged in however without some issue coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as the question is asked, plug the drive in afterwards and it will already know what it is booted from. The addition of the drive will not cause any changes then other than adding new drive in its own location. Either that or go into the boot menu and select the drive to boot from at boot time. This will have the same effect giving the machine no choice to make the wrong decision.

Comment: Yes this worked I was able to use it after going to boot setup.

Comment: Of course it did, when booting you have no way to ensure the drive you want to boot will come online first. Without that it will never know which one to boot from as it will try the first it sees. Now I think installing grub to both of them external drives will get what you want. It booting now matter the drive it finds to boot from. Could lead to problems if getting out of sync with the new kernel installed, you would need to install it to the second one again anytime grub got updated.